# Select options only pass 0

Tags: php, twig, silex

Below is the twig I have for my form

```
<div class="input-group col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
    <span>Type:</span>
    <select name="group-year-type[]" class="form-control year-type">
        <option value="0">Drama</option>
        <option value="1">Non-Drama</option>
    </select>
    <span>Year:</span>
    <input required="require" type="number" min="1950" max="2050" size="16" maxlength="10" class="form-control" name="group-year">
    <span>Status:</span>
    <select name="group-year-status[]" class="form-control year-status">
        <option value="0">Hidden</option>
        <option value="1">Show</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

They passed to my controller as below

```
            $formData = $request->request->all();
            $type = $formData['group-year-type'];
            $year = $formData['group-year-status'];
            $status = $formData['group-year-status'];
            $detect = '';
            $this->app['query']->insertDrama($type,$year,$status);
```

While my Module would put them into db as below

```
function insertDrama($type,$year,$status){
    $sql = array(
        'year_type' => $type,
        'year' => $year,
        'year_status'=>$status,
    );
    return $this->app['db']->insert('drama_cat', $sql);
}
```

Im not sure why, `year` is inserted properly but both my `status` and `type` are always with value `0`. Please help.

Comment: remove `[]` from your name attributes from your select box . Make them like `name="group-year-status"` and so on

Comment: Yes it is the reason, I actually checked it before but I just found out that my js is cached so it wasnt changed in DOM. But why does the array bother it while it does not affect the `year`. Also it bugs me when it always somehow cached my js. I m using Silex 1.3 and Chrome browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `[]` from your name attributes from your select box . Make them like `name="group-year-status"` and so on.

Problem is it's create an array like below:-

```
Array(
    'group-year-status'=>Array(
           0 => 'your selected value'
     )
);
```

And that's why some-how at the time of fetching it always getting `0`

Note:- I don't know `Silex` framework and how it interprets `$formData`, but the root cause of problem is this only.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alive to Die, you make me Die to Alive

Comment: @warmjaijai   ha-ha-ha.Thanks.Glad to help you :):)